# Excel VBA event to calculate based on user input

Tags: excel, vba

To preface the situation, I am new to VBA programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have two columns; one where the user can input a dollar value ("AL") and another where the user can input a percent value ("AK"). The object is to enable the user to input either value (% or $) and have the other value calculate. For instance, if the user inputs 10% in "AL", the applicable $ value will generate in "AK" and vice versa.

Below is the code I've come up with thus far but it isn't working. Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim cell As Range
   Set cell = Range("AK9:AL50")
   'Application.EnableEvents = False Application.EnableEvents = True'

   If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Column = 37 Then ' Value in first column changed
        Range("AL" & Target.Row).Value = Range("AK" & Target.Row).Value / Range("V" & Target.Row).Value
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Target.Column = 38 Then ' value in second column changed
        Range("AK" & Target.Row).Value = Range("AL" & Target.Row).Value * Range("V" & Target.Row).Value
        Exit Sub
    'Application.EnableEvents = False Application.EnableEvents = True'
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a better use of your `Worksheet_Change` parameters, like `Target`.

1.Instead of:

```
Range("AL" & Target.Row).Value
```

you can use:

```
Target.Offset(, 1).Value
```

2.Instead of:

```
Range("AK" & Target.Row).Value
```

you can use:

```
Target.Value
```

3.Also `Range(Target.Address)` actually is `Target`

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Range("AK9:AL50")

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Column = 37 Then ' Value in first column changed
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Target.Value / Range("V" & Target.Row).Value
    ElseIf Target.Column = 38 Then ' value in second column changed
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = Target.Value * Range("V" & Target.Row).Value
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True '<-- RESTORE SETTING OUTSIDE THE IF

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great! To build on the above, I am trying to determine the most efficient way to expand this out... I need the code you provided for 5 different "sets" for lack of a better word. (i.e., column 37&38; 39&40; 41&42; 44&45; 52&53). Right now I'm running these all separately and it works but I'm trying to improve efficiency of the code. Any suggetstions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `Exit Sub`s

And the `Application.EnableEvents = True` needs to be outside the if.

The first time you ran it with the `Application.EnableEvents = False` line enabled it turned off the events and since you exited the sub before turning them back on it stayed off and the sub was never called again.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim cell As Range
   Set cell = Range("AK9:AL50")
   Application.EnableEvents = False

   If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Column = 37 Then ' Value in first column changed
        Range("AL" & Target.Row).Value = Range("AK" & Target.Row).Value / Range("V" & Target.Row).Value

    ElseIf Target.Column = 38 Then ' value in second column changed
        Range("AK" & Target.Row).Value = Range("AL" & Target.Row).Value * Range("V" & Target.Row).Value

    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

My guess is right now your events are disabled.

Run this code after putting the correct code above in your sheet:

```
Sub foooo()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This will turn the events back on.  It is only needed once.